# How to enable dragging in QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, draggable, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to put two pictures in the `QGraphicsScene`. One is fixed and the other one is movable. But I succeed only in putting those pictures in the `QGraphicsScene`, I can't move them. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Items should be movable by default, how are you moving it?

Comment: I don't know why I can't move that. But it's moving now, after I applied the solution below.

Comment: @cnebrera : actually, according to [the doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum), all flags are disabled by default.

Comment: @Jérôme I believe you, but I'm using tons of graphic items and moving them and doing dynamic slides and I have never had to set that flag to true. It is weird XD.

Comment: @cnebrera 
may be it is different in different versions. I am using 4.6(windows  xp)

Comment: @Jérôme I'm using 4.6 too, I will have another look at the code, now I really feel curious about it XD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make sure the item is movable. Have a look at [QGraphicsItem::setFlag](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlag).

You'll have to do something like this :

```
myImageItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
```